# Trigger one async call after another is resolved

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to learn something about async controller in asp.net

so i created one controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SummonerController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("[action]/{name}")]
    public async Task<SummonerDTO> GetSummonerData(string name)
    {
        SummonerEndPoint endPoint = new SummonerEndPoint();
        Task<SummonerDTO> data =  endPoint.GetSummonerData(name);
        var readed = await data;
        MatchesEndPoint endPoint2 = new MatchesEndPoint();
        var data2 = endPoint2.GetMatches(data.Result.accountId.ToString());
        var readed2 = await data2;
        return await endPoint.GetSummonerData(name);
    }
}
```

As you can see in second request i use data i receive from first one.
I am aware of that there is a chance that second request will be resolved before first one. 
So my question is is there a way  to make sure that second call is triggered after first one ended?

combining both results into one dto is another thing but i wont put it to this question

Comment: Why do you think the second request might return before the first one?

Comment: I found 3 awaits one by another on this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-make-multiple-web-requests-in-parallel-by-using-async-and-await  and there i found : Run the program several times to verify that the three tasks don’t always finish in the same order and that the order in which they finish isn't necessarily the order in which they’re created and awaited. There is great possibility that i missunderstood that though

Comment: data will complete before data2 begins in your example.

Comment: If you `await` the task, which you're already doing, you're fine. They would only overlap if you call the async method and don't `await` it.

Comment: @GeorgeHelyar thanks for the confirmation. Put it please as the answer and i will accept it tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `await` the `Task`, which you're already doing, you're fine. They would only overlap if you call the async method and don't `await` it.

As a side note,

```
var result = await task;
```

waits for a task to complete asynchronously and gets the result.

```
var result = task.Result;
```

waits for a task synchronously (blocking the thread).

You can change your code to

```
var summonerEndPoint = new SummonerEndPoint();
var summonerData =  await summonerEndPoint.GetSummonerData(name);
var matchesEndPoint = new MatchesEndPoint();
var matches = await matchesEndPoint.GetMatches(summonerData.accountId.ToString());
return summonerData;
```